# How to make an Android program identify 'if' function?

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner trying to make an counting app. I used videos from [thenewboston's](http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCJbPGzawDH1njbqV-D5HqKw) channel to produce this.

```
package com.example.tasbih2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

int counter;
Button tap, reset;
TextView display, words;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    counter = 0;
    tap = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resetbutton);
    words = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.words);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter);

    if (counter > 10){
        words.setText("C");
    }
    else if (counter > 7){
        words.setText("B");
    }
    else{
        words.setText("A");
    }

    //This is the command to add a count
    tap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter++;
            display.setText(" " + counter);
        }
    });

    reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter = 0;
            display.setText(" " + counter);
        }
    });
}
```

I tried running the program lots of times. I wanted the app so that when the counter reaches a specific number, the writing on top of the number changes. Somehow, it when the counter reaches the number 8, the writing on top does not change. I tried using the 'while' function. However, that just crashed my app. Can someone suggest to me how should I make my program so that the 'if' function gets regularly checked if the counter reaches a certain number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code isn't working because `onCreate()` is only called when the activity is created for the first time and since your logic is inside it it is never called again. So now you are changing values on button click so move your logic there and it'll be called everytime whenever the button is clicked. Simply change your code to this :

```
    //This is the command to add a count
    tap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter++;
            display.setText(" " + counter);
            if (counter > 10){
             words.setText("C");
            }
            else if (counter > 7){
             words.setText("B");
            }
            else{
             words.setText("A");
            }
          }
      });

    reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter = 0;
            display.setText(" " + counter);
            words.setText("A");
         }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the if statements into here:

```
tap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        counter++;

        if (counter > 10){
            words.setText("C");
        } else if (counter > 7){
            words.setText("B");
        } else {
            words.setText("A");
        }

        display.setText(" " + counter);
    }
});
```

This way it's checked every time the `counter` is incremented.

You'll also need to reset it when you reset the counter:

```
reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        counter = 0;
        words.setText("A");
        display.setText(" " + counter);
    }
});
```